# Support of keyboard in application designed primarily for tablets

Tags: touch-screen, keyboard, tablet

I design application for Windows tablet (touch interactions). The application can be also installed on a desktop or laptop.

I need to decide if we should support keyboard as input. The flow in the application is linear and it's mostly about through defined number of steps.

My first thought: Next / back buttons supported with keys "<-" and "->", closing a popup window with a key "esc". Any thoughts on that?

Do you know if there are any standards that I could use? Any standard Microsoft documents or maybe some patterns that are used in similar applications?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that since the app you are designing also works on a desktop or laptop (devices with keyboards as input devices), they provide an experience that a user who connects a keyboard to a touch device also expect to have.

You will also reinforce the experience across devices, regardless of the platform the user is using.

Answer (score 0):

As the app can be used on non-touchscreen computers I would implement it provided that:

- it does not trigger User errors,
- including support for that is not a hard task from the development standpoint.